# Fill ComboBox with data from ObservableCollection from other ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, observablecollection

I have a ComboBox in ViewModel1 and I need to fill it and update it with a list that's in another ViewModel2

XAML

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllLocations}"/>
```

ViewModel1

```
private ObservableCollection<Location> _allLocations = new ObservableCollection<Location>();
public ObservableCollection<Location> AllLocations
{
    get { return _allLocations; }
    set { _allLocations = value; RaisePropertyChanged("AllLocations"); }
}
```

ViewModel2 (this Collection I want to use in ViewModel1 to bind with ComboBox

```
private ObservableCollection<Location> _locations = new ObservableCollection<Location>();
public ObservableCollection<Location> Locations //Binds with the listbox
{
    get { return _locations; }
    set { _locations = value; }
}
```

How do I get the ObservableCollection from ViewModel2 to ViewModel1. It should also automatically update any changes that have been made.

Comment: Where ViewModel2 instance is located? Is it property of ViewModel1? How can ViewModel1 access ViewModel2 instance?

Comment: These are 2 different viewmodels and are not interacting with each other. I need to get access to the ObservableCollection from ViewModel2 to fill the comboBox.

Comment: Do you want changes made with Locations ObservableCollection be applied to AllLocation collection?

Comment: found the solution by passing ViewModel2 as a parameter in ViewModel1 constructor

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What did the trick is using ViewModel2 as a paramater in ViewModel1. This way you can get access to the ObservableCollection Locations in ViewModel 2

ViewModel1

```
private ObservableCollection<Location> _allLocations;
public ObservableCollection<Location> AllLocations
{
    get { return _allLocations; }
    set { _allLocations = value; RaisePropertyChanged("AllLocations"); }
}

public ViewModel1(ViewModel2 vm2 )
{

    AllLocations = vm2.Locations;
}
```